# match all characters in a string independent of their order in the sequence

Tags: java, regex

I want to match certain group of characters in a String independent of their order in the String using regex fucntion. However, the only requirement is that they all must be there.

I have tried

```
String elD = "15672";
String t = "12";
if ((elD.matches(".*[" + t + "].*"))) {
    System.out.println(elD);
}
```

This one checks whether any of the characters are present. But I want all of them to be there.

Also I tried

```
String elD = "15672";
String t = "12";
if ((elD.matches(".*(" + t + ").*"))) {
    System.out.println(elD);
}
```

This does not work as well. I have searched quite a while but I could not find an example when all of the characters from the pattern must be present in the String independent of their order.

Thanks

Comment: try splitting t, and then adding .* in middle of every letter. So it will be like .*t[0].*t[1].*t[2].......

Comment: This is rather inconvenient. I will use the procedure many times not just once so I can't split every time manually but thanks anyway!

Comment: you dont have to split it manually. You can write a small code

Comment: Do you really need to use regex here?

Comment: Well this is rather simple task. I thought there must be a built-in regex expression in Java for that since using regex is more elegant than looping through the sequence?

Comment: `independent of their order in the String` and `they all must be there in some order` ... could you clarify this. your example `elD` & `t` are not very clear in this regard.

Comment: Sorry. The only requirement is that the characters must be there. I have corrected it in my post as well

Comment: Pshemo if this cannot be done via regex then I am open for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write regex for this but it would not look nice. If you would want to check if your string contains anywhere `x` and `y` you would need to use few times [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) like

```
^(?=.*x)(?=.*y).*$
```

and use it like

```
yourStirng.matches(regex);
```

But this way you would need to create your own method which would generate you dynamic regex and add `(?=.*X)` for each character you want to check. You would also need to make sure that this character is not special in regex like `?` or `+`.

Simpler and not less effective solution would be creating your own method which would check if your string contains all searched characters, something like

```
public static boolean containsUnordered(String input, String searchFor){
    char[] characters = searchFor.toCharArray();
    for (char c: characters)
        if (!input.contains(String.valueOf(c)))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I will play the secure way then with the loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can built a pattern from the search string using the `replaceAll` method:

```
String s = "12";

String pattern = s.replaceAll("(.)", "(?=[^$1]*$1)");
```

Note: You can't test the same character several times. *(i.e. `112` gives `(?=[^1]*1)(?=[^1]*1)(?=[^2]*2)` that is exactly the same as `(?=[^1]*1)(?=[^2]*2)`)*

But in my opinion Pshemo method is probably more efficient.